# JSoup doesn't parse Android Known Issues Page

Tags: android, jsoup

I am using JSoup to download and parse the Android Issues Page. This is my code so far:

```
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(
                "http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/static.py?page=known_issues.cs");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(url, 5000);
        EditText bla;
        bla = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        bla.setText(document.toString());
        if (document.toString().contains("recentfixes")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "YES", 1).show();
        }
```

Well, the weird thing is, that the WHOLE page is parsed, BUT the section with recent fixes. [This](http://pastebin.com/szcngcUD) is a wget output and [this](http://pastebin.com/2Zc8QyvL) is the parsed output.

Can you help me with that?

Comment: Are there any other HTML parsers you can try? I've found that http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/ is quite robust.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't parse the recent fixes either... this is weird.

Comment: Have you tried parsing the whole document as a string, rather than relying on the network request? I wonder if the `static.py` service is filtering content based on requester. Look at how Jsoup or HtmlCleaner is requested the page, and print out the data. If the recent stories information is there, take the string response and run it through both parser. If both still fail, create a minimal failing test-case and log an issue against both cleaners.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. `System.out.println(Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/static.py?page=known_issues.cs").get().toString().contains("recentfixes"));` just gives `true`.

Comment: Ah, if I use connect() instead of parse() it works. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Force, Could you write your fix as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using .connect instead.

The following should give you the entire page's text:

```
URL url = null;
try {
    url = new URL(
            "http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/static.py?page=known_issues.cs");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(0).get();
    String entireText = document.text();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The question is from october 2011, just thought you should know.

Comment: Answered for posterity.